# How can i replace column values, to all my columns with the same reference using a script

Tags: excel, excel-formula, replace, reference

can someone help me to replace all column values where column reference is equal to another column reference

For example: I have this reference N01781124 [Column A27] with 1,00 value [Column C27] and i want it to replace it to the same column reference [Column F9] and set the value to [Column H9]

[image: Excel Example]

I have more than 3000 references with aleatory order and a script would save me a lot of time.

I tried to find similar posts but the closest thing i saw was using this code:

```
=IF(A27=F9;C27;H9)
```

Problem is this only replace it one by one, and i want it to do it with a Excel script, so when i get some values changes i can run it and replace it fast. Thanks

Comment: I believe you are looking for: `=VLOOKUP(A27, F:H, 3, False)`  That says "Lookup the value in `A27` in column `F`, the left-most column of the range `F:H` and return the value that is 3 columns to the right.

Comment: I want to return the value C27, not the H9, and how can i look for all rows without telling him it has to look at A27

Comment: It's the same formula, just change the arguments. `=VLOOKUP(F27, A:C, 3, False)`, or more robust `=If(ISNA(VLOOKUP(F27, A:C, 3, False)), H9, VLOOKUP(F27, A:C, 3, False))` The big important take-away is that the function [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) exists and does what you need it to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub CopyValues()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRowA As Long
    Dim LastRowF As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    ' Specify the worksheet where you want to perform the operation
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName")
    
    ' Find the last row in columns A and F
    LastRowA = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowF = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through each cell in column F
    For i = 1 To LastRowF
        ' Compare the reference in column F with references in column A
        For j = 1 To LastRowA
            If ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = ws.Cells(j, 1).Value Then
                ' If there's a match, copy the value from column C to column H
                ws.Cells(i, 8).Value = ws.Cells(j, 3).Value
                Exit For ' Exit the inner loop once a match is found
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```